# How to match duplicate letters in interjections

Tags: r, regex

I'm working on interjections with duplicate letters, for example:

```
x <- c("hallelujah", "hey", "tarrah", "yeah", "bubye", "eureka", "aha", "cooee", "helloee") # "hey" and "yeah" are included as controls
```

I understand that backreference is key to matching duplicates. For example, `(\\w)\\1` matches interjections that contain a duplicated letter in *immediately next position*:

```
grep("(\\w)\\1", x, value = T)
[1] "hallelujah" "tarrah"     "cooee"      "helloee"
```

However, what I don't understand is why this extended pattern fails to match **all** interjections that contain a duplicated letter *whatever the position of the dupe* although the `*`quantifier should allow the preceding `.` to occur any number of times including zero:

```
grep("(\\w).*\\1", x, value = T)
[1] "hallelujah" "bubye"      "eureka"     "aha"
```

and why, to match exhaustively, the pattern must include `.*` at the beginning:

```
grep(".*(\\w).*\\1", x, value = T)
[1] "hallelujah" "tarrah"     "bubye"      "eureka"     "aha"        "cooee"      "helloee"
```

Can anybody explain why?

Comment: Try it with `perl=TRUE`.

Comment: Yes, indeed, that works! But why?

Comment: Per default you use [TRE](https://github.com/laurikari/tre/)